# How do I find the difference between the next minimum cost and the least minimum cost

Tags: r, sorting, optimization, min

I have a list of files that has tables in this format. The table dimension may differ.
I want to find the difference between the second minimum cost and the least minimum cost in each rows and each column.

In this example, I want to replace **max** with the second minimum cost. I don't know how to get that.

```
data
r_data = nrow(data)
col_data = ncol(data)



cost = data[1:(r_data-1), 1:(col_data-1)]
## cost for the table
supply = data[1:(r_data-1),col_data]
demand = data[r_data, 1:(col_data-1)]

cost
supply
demand

## for the rows difference
min_dif_row <- apply(cost, 1, max) - apply(cost, 1, min)
min_dif_row
```

The output for min_dif_row should be
5 1 1 and not 58 73 73.

Thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: (a) Can you please share a little bit of sample data in copy/pasteable format? (b) What do you want to happen if there are ties? If there are 2 maximums, are they both replaced? If there are 2 values tied for the minimums, is the difference 0 and is the "second minimum" the same as the first?

Comment: For the min diff, you could try `apply(cost, 1, function(x) abs(diff(x[rank(x) %in% c(1, 2)])))`, but you probably should set a `ties.method` argument for `rank`, and there may need to be adjustments based on your answers to my questions above.

Comment: ##   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   67   14   18    9
[2,]   76    3   21    4
[3,]   47    4   77    5       ## The minimum is 9 and the next minimum is 14. If there is a tie, the second minimum is used so difference cannot be 0.

Comment: Could you please share the data with `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable? `dput(data[1:5, 1:3])` would be great.

Comment: dput(data = matrix(c(67,14,18,9,38,76,3,21,4,20,47,4, 77,5,18,5, 24,35,12, 76), ncol= 5, byrow = TRUE))

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
sec_min <- function(x) {
  xs <- sort(x)
  xs[which(diff(xs) > 0)[1] + 1]
}

min_dif_row <- apply(cost, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sec_min) - apply(cost, 1, min)
```

Say after sorting a row you have something like: `3 3 4 5 7`. The function returns `4` which is the second minimum.

Or even **more elegantly:**

```
sec_min <- function(x) {
  unique(sort(x))[[2]]
}
min_dif_row <- apply(cost, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sec_min) - apply(cost, 1, min)
```

Comment: thanks so much. It worked. I would not mind if you can explain the "which" in the function.

Comment: `which` returns the indices of a vector, array or list which satisfy a certain condition. In this case the condition was that the difference between 2 consecutive numbers should be greater than 0.